# unsure of correct syntax for before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to create a splash page.  I found this [post](http://%20before_filter%20redirect_to%20root_path) but I can't seem to get the syntax right for the before_filter.  Here's what I've got:

```
 before_filter redirect_to root_path
```

(I changed the root path to be the splash page.)

But it pops out this error:

```
Routing Error

undefined local variable or method `root_path' for ApplicationController:Class
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clarification: root_path exists as an instance  method, not as a class method during the class setup.  thus the block or method call is needed to defer the call or root_path to the actual time of the call, not during the loading of the class.

For some reason someone deleted the correct answer:  move it to a block form:

```
before_filter do
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

assuming the root_path points to :index, you could:

```
before_filter(:except => :index) do
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: I dig this solution, but the problem is that it creates a redirect loop.  When rails wants to go to root, it tries to redirect to root.  Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Comment: check out conditions in http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html   .....   `:except =>`

Comment: Cool.  So I popped in this, which is nice.  But it thinks the first "root_path" is an undefined variable or method.  I'm not sure of what syntax I should be using.  Any suggestions?  ` before_filter(:except => root_path) do
   redirect_to root_path,
 end`

Comment: not root_path, but the name of the method root_path points to

Comment: That still gives me the undefined variable method.  Am I writing it wrong? ` before_filter(:except => pages_splash_path) do
   redirect_to root_path
 end`

Comment: when it goes to the root_path,what's the name of the controller method it goes to? add a colon to it.  ie, `root :to => "home#index"` means `:except => :index`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much for your help!  This is what I ended up with: ` before_filter(:except => :splash) do
   redirect_to root_path
 end`

Answer (score 1):

`rake routes` and make sure `root` is defined.

e.g. that you have `root :to => "home#index"` at the bottom of your routes.rb file.

Replace home#index with a real controller/action

Comment: I tried to pop in this code, but it created a feedback loop so that when I navigate to root, rails tries to redirect to root. ` before_filter do
  redirect_to pages_splash_path
 end`  How would I tell rails to only redirect if the active page is NOT root?

Comment: So when I do what you suggest, I get a new error error: `NameError in PagesController#splash

undefined local variable or method `pages_splash_path' for #<PagesController'  The thing is this action is definted in the pages controller, so it should be OK.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks the the method is defined, but the code has an error.  Look at that method.  Post the code from that method. It probably has a redirect to pages_splash_path.  Check which paths exist with `rake routes` and make sure that pages_splash is listed.  Check your config/routes.rb to see if the path is defined.  If not then add it (read on up routes if necessary).